# How would I interact with an object with no name?

Tags: python

How would I go about interacting with an instance of a class that isn't created directly by me, similar to below:

```
Matrix = [[MyClass() for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
```

I'm attempting to read some information from each instance at each index of the Matrix, such a number like anyNum = 9. How would I go about doing this since I didn't assign a name to each instance?

Comment: But the instance is created directly by you in the example. And variable anynum is not part of your code, why do you mention it? You could simply assign a name to the element of a list at a specific index. Why don't you do it?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. I agree with @Trilarion, I'm not sure I understand what the issue is here.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of lists, so simply iterate:

```
for my_list in Matrix:
    for obj in my_list:
        do_something(obj)
```

Here, `obj` is an instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: Thank you. I remembered that almost as soon as I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object via indexing:

```
anyNum = Matrix[0][0]
```